# Slide gesture to go back in combination with navigationBarHidden set to YES

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

The title pretty much says it all. I'm using storyboards and when i show my navigation bar and go into a view controller I can go back by using the Back button in the navigation bar or swipe to the right from the left side of the screen.

Now when I hide the navigation bar by either setting the navigationBarHidden property to YES or by unchecking the 'Shows navigation bar' in the storyboard I no longer see the navigation bar (that's what I want) but I also can no longer use the swipe gesture to go back.

Oh and it only needs to work on iOS 7.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution is pretty simple:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does the trick. Also had to add <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> to the @interface.